# In Quantum imaging with undetected photons, why is the idler photon sent through a second non-linear crystal if it is then discarded?

Tags: quantum-entanglement, non-linear-optics, imaging

I've been reading up on quantum ghost imaging and other similar approaches. In particular, I'm reading a paper [Quantum Imaging with Undetected Photons by Gabriela B. Lemos et al](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1401/1401.4318.pdf) and trying to understand why the Idler photon (red signal in path d going from D1 to D2) is sent into NL2 given it is being discarded at D5.

The question is if D2 was removed and therefore the idler photon from D1 did not go to NL2, would that kill the experiment? Would it still be capable of forming an image of the object O?

[image: Experimental setup]

Comment: Do you mean "discarded at D5" ?

Comment: No, I do not mean discarded at D5. I do not understand why the idler (red) is being sent to NL2 unless that triggers NL2 to produce two down-converted photons. Is that the case?

Comment: there is no $D_3$ in the figure (which is probably what the other comment was referring to)

Comment: Apologies, Keith yes I meant discarded at D5.